# Clean way to create dom elements based on data from array?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I have an array full of objects that have the same keys, but different values.  These objects need to be turned into divs with various sub elements.  The following code works, but seems messy and hard to maintain.

```js
pim.buildProducts = function(array) {
     // for each item in the array
     productHTML = '';
     compareBoxHTML =   '<div class="checkbox compare">' +
                        '<label data-placement="right" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Add to Compare"><span class="compare-text">Compare</span><input type="checkbox" value="compare"></label>' +
                    '</div>';

     for(i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
         // build image
         image = '<div class="image"><a href="' + array[i].url + '"><img src="' + array[i].image + '" /></a></div>';

         // build description
         desc = '<div class="desc"><h4><a href="' + array[i].image + '">' + array[i].id + '</a></h4>' +
    '<h5>' + array[i].description + '</h5>';

         // build icons
          icons = '<div class="pim-icons"><a class="cart" href="' + array[i].url + '"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span></a>';
         if(array[i].catalog) {
             icons += '<a class="file" href="' + array[i].catalog + '"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-file"></span></a>';
         }
         icons += '</div>';
         productHTML += '<div class="product">' + image + desc + icons + '</div>';
}
     return productHTML;
 };
```

Are there better ways of doing this, or other options that I could pursue?

Thanks!
Walter

Comment: While it might seem "cleaner" to build the DOM elements using Javascript functions, it's not necessarily the best way for performance. Browsers have highly optimized HTML parsers, while performing lots of incremental DOM updates from JS can be pretty slow.

Comment: If you _are_ going to use `createElement`, make sure you add nodes to a `docfrag` first, and then add the frag to the DOM.

Comment: @Barmar That's why I originally went with this method.  When dealing with hundreds of elements, it seemed better (performance wise) to output them all at once instead of creating them one-by-one.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could use `document.createElement` and the other DOM methods instead of writing HTML, but that may be even more verbose than using an HTML string.

Another option would be to use a template function like what lodash provides, which would make the HTML a lot cleaner.

The JS becomes:

```
pim.buildProducts = function(array) {
  var tplHtml = document.getElementById('productsTpl').innerHTML;
  var tpl = _.template(tplHtml);
  return tpl({ products: array });
}
```

And you could put the template in your HTML file:

```
<script type="text/template" id="productsTpl">
  <% products.forEach(function(item) { %>   
  <div class="product">
    <div class="image">
      <a href="<%= item.url %>">
        <img src="<%= item.image %>" />
      </a>
    </div>
    <div class="desc">
      <h4><a href="<%= item.image %>"><%= item.id %></a></h4>
      <h5><%= item.description %></h5>
      <div class="pim-icons">
        <a class="cart" href="<%= item.url %>">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-shopping-cart"></span>
        </a>
        <% if (item.catalog) { %>
        <a class="file" href="<%= item.catalog %>">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-file"></span>
        </a>
        <% } %>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <% }) %>
</script>
```

Comment: I didn't downvote, but it's probably because you didn't show how to use it for what he wants.

Comment: Oh, thanks for clarifying. I added a full Lodash example. I think using DOM methods for anything complex would end up being about as tedious as the original string concatenation solution.

Comment: Thanks for this answer.  I didn't end up using it, or any other answer for now, but this pointed me in the right direction for future projects.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know this is the cleanest way to do it.

First of all you should create all html like this;

```
    <div hidden="hidden" id="mainDiv">
    <div class="checkbox compare">   
    <label data-placement="right" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Add to Compare">
        <span class="compare-text">Compare</span>
        <input type="checkbox" value="compare">
    </label>
</div>
<div class="image">
    <a href="">
        <img src="">
    </a>
</div>
</div>
```

After that you should make the parent div hidden, and clone it to an object with [.clone()](https://api.jquery.com/clone/). After that you just simply change values of the element like;

```
    <script>
function fillData(array)
{
    for(var i ; i<array.length;i++)
    {
        var element = $("#mainDiv").clone();
        element.attr("hidden","");
        element.find("img").attr("id",array[i].url);
        $(document).append(element);
    }
}
</script>
```

and append to where ever you want.

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion - pretty clever usage of clone!  I don't always use Jquery, but most of the projects I'm working in have it.  I ended up not using this answer (or any of the others), but I will keep it in mind for future projects.  I'd vote it up if I could.

Answer (score -1):

Take a look to [document.createElement](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_nodes.asp) function and all others for DOM handling